# How to underline and bold button text through script (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, uibutton, underline

How can I underline and bold UI button text through my script in Unity3D? I'm creating the buttons dynamically based on the number required in the game.

Answer (score 3):

You can use rich text tags:

```
<u>underline text</u>

<b>bold text</b>

<u><b>underline bold text</b></u>
```

In Unity:

```
textfield.text = "<u><b>hello world</b></u>";
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, I'm accessing the buttons through an array as such:
`buttons[i].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().color = Color.red;`. So I'm guessing I can't use rich text tags in that way?

Comment: You can: `buttons[i].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "<b>bold text</b>";`

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but since it is one of the first Google results, I wanted to respond.

You cannot use the  underline  rich text tag with a standard Unity UI Text Game Object.

HOWEVER, you can do it with a Text-TextMeshPro GameObject. So, I recommend using TextMeshPro if you want to use underline or strikethrough.

Answer (score 0):

Unity 3d supports rich text, but no the underline tag `<u></u>`:

[Rich Text Support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/StyledText.html)

If you really need text to be underlined. You will need to overlay some sort of object or component that looks like an underline. For example writing text just underneath using something like "____" etc.